# ffmpeg specify stream by handler_name

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, gopro

I've got a file with these streams

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 45315 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:57.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 19:51:39:46
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:57.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 19:51:39:46
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:57.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 19:51:39:46
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:57.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro MET
    Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 14 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:57.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro SOS
```

And would like to output only Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067)

I can map it  with -map 0:3, but some files have that same Stream in a different position, like this:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60013 kb/s, 90 fps, 90 tbr, 90k tbn, 180 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:25.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:25.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 35 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:25.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro MET
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 18 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-12T19:32:25.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro SOS
```

How can I make sure I'm selecting the right one? I've tried with -map 0:m:handler_name:"        GoPro MET" and things like that, but I'm always getting an error:

> Stream map '0:m:handler_name:GoPro_MET' matches no streams.

Note that I had never used ffmpeg before and might be missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved. I had tried including spaces before the GoPro MET handler name, but actually a TAB was needed:

-map 0:m:handler_name:" GoPro MET"